# Modified dicee program not working as intended in flutter

Tags: flutter

Can someone explain why this program is not running as intended.
The program is written in `flutter`.

is there something wrong with the `onPress` function?
or is there something wrong with the `if` statement in the function?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dicee'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

     
    class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
    }
     
    class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
      int _leftdiceNumber=1;
      int _rightdiceNumber=1;
     
     onPress(String value) {
        setState(() {
          if (value == 'left' && _leftdiceNumber == 6) {
            _leftdiceNumber = 1;
          } else {
            _leftdiceNumber = _leftdiceNumber++;
          }
     
          if (value == 'right' && _rightdiceNumber == 6) {
            _rightdiceNumber = 1;
          } else {
            _rightdiceNumber = _rightdiceNumber++;
          }
        });
      }
        
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Left button got pressed ${_leftdiceNumber}');
                    onPress('left');
                  },
                  child: Image.asset('images/dice${_leftdiceNumber}.png'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Right button got pressed ${_rightdiceNumber}');
                    onPress('right');
                  },
                  child: Image.asset('images/dice${_rightdiceNumber}.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add all image assets to pupspec.yaml file?
Also please explain more what is not working as intended

Comment: there are only 6 images (i.e. from dice1.png to dice6.png)

Comment: Please check the answer by @TanujWagh for more information the errors of this program and its solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is creating the given problem -

```
onPress(String value) {
    setState(() {
      if (value == 'left' && _leftdiceNumber == 6) {
        _leftdiceNumber = 1;
      } else {
        _leftdiceNumber = _leftdiceNumber++;
      }
 
      if (value == 'right' && _rightdiceNumber == 6) {
        _rightdiceNumber = 1;
      } else {
        _rightdiceNumber = _rightdiceNumber++;
      }
    });
  }
```

The

```
_leftdiceNumber = _leftdiceNumber++;
_rightdiceNumber = _rightdiceNumber++;
```

are ambiguous operation and intern are doing nothing, except resetting values to their old value.

Consider this operation -

```
_leftdiceNumber = _leftdiceNumber++;
```

starts with incrementing _leftdiceNumber, and then reverting _leftdiceNumber to the old value as _leftdiceNumber++ returns the not incremented value.In short it does nothing.

This will suffice the problem

```
_leftdiceNumber++;
```

Also looking at the If-else logic, the onPress() will increase value for _leftdiceNumber as we for right_rightdiceNumber, It can be updated as follows -

```
onPress(String value) {
    setState(() {
      if (value == 'left') {
        if (_leftdiceNumber == 6) {
          _leftdiceNumber = 1;
        } else {
          _leftdiceNumber++;
        }
      } else {
        if (_rightdiceNumber == 6) {
          _rightdiceNumber = 1;
        } else {
          _rightdiceNumber++;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As you have two sapearte dice that need to roll independent when someone taps on them with the old if else logic if the user press left dice onPress("left") will.be fired. Coming to the if else first check if(value== 'left' && _leftDiceNumber ==6) will excute correctly while the next if else if(value=='right' && _rightDiceNumber == 6) else part will also be executed and vice versa.